Do neutrinos have a $4π$-symmetry the same as electrons have?
We know that all charged elementary ferrmion particles  (i.e. spin-1/2 elementary particles) have a Dirac $4π$-symmetry meaning that they return the same phase after two $2π$ rotations (i.e. 720°) in the lab frame measured.
Does the same apply also for the chargeless neutrinos? Do neutrinos possessing also a 4π-symmetry like electrons or else? And can this be measured in the lab?

Any particle with half-integer*N spin where N=1,3,5... (composite or not) has a 4π symmetry which means that it can be represented by a spinor.
Any particle with integer spin (composite or not) has a 2π symmetry which means it can be represented by a vector.
Fermions have half-integer*N spin and bosons have integer spin.Since neutrinos are fermions they have 4π symmetry.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
